VB.Net application only scaling correctly at 150%
I have developed a VB.Net application on a computer where the display scaling is set to 150%, and with dpiAware being set to True in the app.manifest, it renders perfectly. But whenever i switch scaling to 100%, or try it on another PC where scaling is set to 100%, the controls don't position themselves properly and the application doesn't look as it does on 150% scaling. The problem is fixed however when the user goes into the executable's properties and changes the high DPI settings manually from there, but that is something I don't want the users of displays with 100% scaling to do as it adds another unnecessary layer of complexity.

app.manifest tells us that it's .NET Framework and the version is <= 4.7. No? Do you have the Windows 10 in the compatibility section uncommented? Generally, Scale 100% to design or use layout panels (Panel, FLP, TLP, ...) to properly lay out the UI elements. See High DPI support in Windows Forms.
